# When would Blender be recommended?

Tags: animation, workflow

What is blender and how is it useful? Would it be recommended for beginners? 
I am starting animation and I'm trying to find what to start with. I saw Blender a few times during my research and got curious.

Comment: I think that the first part of [this post in the Blender developer](https://code.blender.org/2013/10/redefining-blender/) blog can give you some hits about the overall philosophy. BTW, give it a try!

Comment: This isn't really the type of question we usually handle here, we're more setup for specific workflow and technical questions.  That said, (and I think I'm speaking for most of us here) I think Blender is awesome and anybody (including beginners) should try it out!

Comment: I was a 3d studio max user for 10 years and now I prefer blender. What do you think?

Comment: Sites like http://slant.co are better for soliciting opinions. But asking about tools for beginners is a loaded question since those beginners at some point might want to use their skills for real projects too.